# Laravel 5.5 - Nested query and model relation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I have 4 models.

- User
- Shipment
- Status
- Status history

`User.php`

```
public function shipments() {
   return $this->hasMany('App\Shipment', 'from_user_id');
}
```

`Shipment.php`

```
public function statuses() {
   return $this->hasMany('App\StatusHistory', 'model_id');
}
```

A `User` has many `Shipment`.
A `Shipment` has many `Status` instances through `StatusHistory`.

How can I get with an Eloquent relationship all the `Shipment` values for an `User`, that have a specific id value in the `StatusHistory` model?

Comment: There isn't enough information in your question to write an actual query. So I'd suggest looking at using `whereHas` when querying `$user->shipments()->whereHas(...)`.

Comment: I just added some more information. So if I have $user->shipments, how can add extra query to that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
$user = User:find($id);
$shipments = $user->shipments()->whereHas('statuses', function ($query) {
    //Select all the shipments for this user where `StatusHistory` id is 1
    $query->where('id', 1);
})->get();
```